# Matrix rotation efficiency

Tags: javascript, optimization, matrix

I am not sure if I should be using recursion or not or if it even helps in increasing the performance of my algorithm. I feel as though I am creating and replacing too many arrays by calling my inner `rotate()` function.

Should I add a check to convert rotation `-270` to `90` and vice-versa so that I am rotating less often?

Please refer to the JSFiddle I have provided for details and clarification on the functions involved in the code below: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/PaCv8/)

```
var rotateMatrix = function (matrix, n, direction) {
    var ret = matrix.slice();

    var rotate = function(direction, matrix) {
        var r = zeroArr(n, n);
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (direction < 0) {
                    r[i][j] = matrix[n - j - 1][i];
                } else {
                    r[i][j] = matrix[j][n - i - 1];
                }
            }
        }
        return r;
    };

    for (var turn = Math.abs(direction); turn > 0; turn -= 90) {
        ret = rotate(direction, ret);
    }

    return ret;
};

var tile = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['D', 'E', 'F'],
    ['G', 'H', 'I']
];

trace2('Rotate +180', printMatrix(rotateMatrix(tile, 3, 180)));
trace2('Rotate +90', printMatrix(rotateMatrix(tile, 3, 90)));
trace2('Orginal', printMatrix(tile));
trace2('Rotate -90', printMatrix(rotateMatrix(tile, 3, -90)));
trace2('Rotate -180', printMatrix(rotateMatrix(tile, 3, -180)));
```

**Output:**

```
Rotate +180:

 I| H| G
--+--+--
 F| E| D
--+--+--
 C| B| A

Rotate +90:

 C| F| I
--+--+--
 B| E| H
--+--+--
 A| D| G

Orginal:

 A| B| C
--+--+--
 D| E| F
--+--+--
 G| H| I

Rotate -90:

 G| D| A
--+--+--
 H| E| B
--+--+--
 I| F| C

Rotate -180:

 I| H| G
--+--+--
 F| E| D
--+--+--
 C| B| A
```

Answer (score 3):

The `n` parameter is redundant, as it should be possible to deduce the matrix dimensions from `matrix` itself, using `matrix.length` and `matrix[0].length`.  You seem to have made the assumption that `matrix` is square — you should either document or relax the restriction.

I suggest writing three separate inner functions for the three possible rotations.  One code-reuse technique you could use for the ±90° rotations is to combine [transpose and row-swap operations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40372/9357).

Comment: Wow, that question was insightful. I have come up with the ollowing: [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/NH42z/). Should I append these changes to my question for others to view? Is there any other way to optimize this?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Concerning changes to reviewed code, you might want to read [this meta-post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/can-i-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-code-also-how-to-handle-iterativ)